# Close tab alert modification

Tags: javascript

So I am starting a new website where we would be providing Professional Resume making services. So not everyone wants to pay for the service some want it free. So the problem for me is when a visitor comes to my site & is leaving I will be adding the "Do you want to leave?" javascript (don't know what it is called as I am not a coder just learnt this stuff in the past week while researching for my website.) so when the visitor tries to leave, the website will ask if they are sure & then when they click on "leave" I want to link the leave button to redirect the visitor to a freebie Resume maker which will be an internal link(Just a way to retain a potential customer). The resume made from there (freebie link) will have our company watermark on it & will give them an option to remove watermark for a cost. So how do I do it? And the script I found while I was researching only works on Edge how do I make it work on all browsers as well? And below is the script I found from a video a few days ago which only works on Edge.

PS:- This is my first Post if I have written something wrong here let me know.

```
<script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var areYouReallySure = false;
function areYouSure() {
    if(allowPrompt){
        if (!areYouReallySure && true) {
            areYouReallySure = true;
            var confMessage = "***************************************Hi*I*am*some*text***************************************";
            return confMessage;
        }
    }else{
        allowPrompt = true;
    }
}

var allowPrompt = true;
window.onbeforeunload = areYouSure;
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I think what you are looking for is how to make a [confirm dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm). You can simplify a lot of your code by following the examples there. Also your code has 2 opening `<script>` tags, so get rid of the first one. You can also remove the `&& true` in the if statement because it's redundant. Finally, from a UX perspective, I will warn you that this will annoy most of the visitors on your site, and they will most likely never come back.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in function `confirm()` which displays a dialog (similar to the one with `alert()`) but lets you choose between the <kbd>Ok</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> buttons.

The function returns a boolean:

- `true` if the user clicked <kbd>Ok</kbd>
- `false` if the user clicked <kbd>Cancel</kbd>

```js
confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?");
```